# While I'm wrting a python code showing all the possible combinations of a list, I cannot clarify why expected results doesn't appear

Tags: python, recursion, combinations

I wanna write a code, which shows all the possible **'toPick' combinations of a list with length 'n'**. Also, I want my function to be a **recursive one**. My code is here:

```
def pick(n, picked, toPick):
    if(toPick==0):
        print(picked)
        return picked[:-1]
    if(len(picked)==0):
        last = 0
    else:
        last = picked[-1]
    for next in range(last+1, n+1):
        picked.append(next)
        picked = pick(n, picked, toPick-1) # What happened here?

pick(5, [], 2)
```

My expected result is:

[1, 2]

[1, 3]

[4, 5]

**but, the result shown on my window is:**

[1, 2]

[1, 3]

[1, 4]

[1, 5]

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

So, I added some lines to detect the errors:

```
def pick(n, picked, toPick):
    if(toPick==0):
        print(picked)
        return picked[:-1]
    if(len(picked)==0):
        last = 0
    else:
        last = picked[-1]
    for next in range(last+1, n+1):
        picked.append(next)
        print("before pick:{}".format(picked)) # I wrote this line to track the error
        picked = pick(n, picked, toPick-1) # What happened here?
        print("after pick:{}".format(picked)) # I wrote this line to track the error

pick(5, [], 2)
```

**but the result was:**

before pick:[1]

before pick:[1, 2]

[1, 2]

after pick:[1]

before pick:[1, 3]

[1, 3]

after pick:[1]

before pick:[1, 4]

[1, 4]

after pick:[1]

before pick:[1, 5]

[1, 5]

after pick:[1]

after pick:None

Traceback (most recent call last):

...

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'

**Could you help me figure out what is wrong?**

Comment: The function doesn't return anything when the first `if` condition fails. So it returns `None`, and the `for` loop sets  `picked` to that, and then you get an error when you try to do `picked.append(next)`

Comment: Ah ha... I got it. Thank you! I should check it.